# NullPointerException in Bubble Sorting with Partial Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Hello people of StackOverflow,

I am currently receiving a NPE every time I run the following code. I am attempting to prompt a user for  some names, and then sort them alphabetically.

Here is the code:

```
    package assignments;

    import global.Cod;

    public class Homework_09 
    {
        public static final int MAXIMUM_NAMES = 20;

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            String names[] = new String[MAXIMUM_NAMES];
            String temp;
            int value = 0;
            int i = 0;
            boolean swap = true;
            boolean done = false;

            System.out.println("Please enter up to 20 names (Press Enter to quit): ");
            do 
            {
                for (value = 0; value <= MAXIMUM_NAMES; value++)
                {
                    names[value] = Cod.next();
                    if (names[value].equals(" ")) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("The sorted names are: ");
                        for (i = 0; i < names.length-1; i++)
                        {
                            while (names[value].compareTo(names[value + 1]) > 0)
                            {
                                temp = names[value];
                                names[value] = names[value + 1];
                                names[value + 1] = temp;
                                done = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
            } while (done == false);

            System.out.println(names[value]);

        }
    }
```

And here is the error:

```
**Please enter up to 20 names (Press Enter to quit): 
ABCDE
ABCD
ABC
AB
A

The sorted names are: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at assignments.Homework_09.main(Homework_09.java:28)**
```

Comment: You need to separate the sort from the user input parsing. First get all the values from the user and then sort. One of the things I see is that you don't exit out of the `for (value = 0; value <= MAXIMUM_NAMES; value++)` section even though user input may have ended. Sit and trace out what you expect to happen vs what is currently happening and add some print statements for debugging.

Comment: [Understanding how to debug your code](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) will enable you to solve problem like this 99% of the time

Answer (score 0):

As @scrappedcola says, you are looping over 19 values, but you have only entered 5 names.  names[6] is null. so you are in effect calling

```
names[5].compareto(null);
```

You might want to break your loop when you hit null, or you might want to count the number of inputs.